# How to force enable release mode in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

It's recommended to test the compose performance in release mode: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/why-should-you-always-test-compose-performance-in-release-4168dd0f2c71.

How does the compose compiler detects if it is in release or debug mode?

Is there a way to force enable compose release mode for certain type of a build?

I have three build types in my app: `debug`, `qa` and `release`:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        matchingFallbacks = ['debug']
    }
    qa {
        applicationIdSuffix '.qa'
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        matchingFallbacks = ['release']
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
    }
}
```

I want to test a new compose feature. But when I build my app with `qa` build type, the compose feature is still laggy. It becomes fast only when I build with `release` build type. However I need to use the `qa` build type, because it includes some extra functionality for QA.

I tried to use flag `android:debuggable="false"` in AndroidManifest, but it didn't help.